# How to detect encoding mismatch

Tags: java, encryption, encoding

I have a bunch of old AES-encrypted Strings encrypted roughly like this:

1. String is converted to bytes with ISO-8859-1 encoding
2. Bytes are encrypted with AES
3. Result is converted to BASE64 encoded char array

Now I would like to change the encoding to UTF8 for new values (eg. '€' does not work with ISO-8859-1). This will of
course cause problems if I try to decrypt the old ISO-8859-1 encoded values with UTF-8 encoding:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<!#[¤%&/()=?^*ÄÖÖÅ_:;>½§@${[]}<|'äöå-.,+´¨]'-Lorem ipsum dolor ...> but was:<!#[�%&/()=?^*����_:;>��@${[]}<|'���-.,+��]'-Lorem ipsum dolor ...>
```

I'm thinking of creating some automatic encoding fallback for this.

So the main question would be that **is it enough to inspect the decrypted char array for '�' characters to figure out encoding mismatch?** And what is the 'correct' way to declare that '�' symbol when comparing?

```
if (new String(utf8decryptedCharArray).contains("�")) {
    // Revert to doing the decrypting with ISO-8859-1
    decryptAsISO...
}
```

Comment: Impossible to know unless you have a specific set of characters that cannot appear on the original string that you can check against on the decrypted string (and of course do appear when encoding to UTF8). The best solution I think is to attach metadata with the actual encoding to use.

Comment: Actually, you have to know _beforehand_ what encoding was used in the bytes you are dealing with. Or you must try some encoding detection which is a somewhat complicated task.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to try decrypting your data with both encodings and analyze the outcome of both?

Comment: The solution @m0skit0 is proposing would work but I would rather want to solve this without having to deal that.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose What should I analyze from the outcome if I try both encodings? In some cases the outcome is same (equals) but in some cases outcome is not same (!equals)... Still don't know which one is correct? Only thing I came up with is to find that '�' character (_It is used to indicate problems when a system is unable to render a stream of data to a correct symbol_)

Comment: Please, show us some more lines of code, as quite probably you're doing something wrong in `new String(utf8decryptedCharArray)`

Comment: You say the 'old' data is ISO-8859-1.  Do you have a date somewhere you can use, telling you when that particular string was encoded?  That would be a good guide to the encoding used.

Comment: @rossum, I don't have a 'date' but as there is no 'new' yet all the values are old. New values could be somehow marked as 'UTF8'... But in a way I did already decide to do encoding migration as RalfKleberhoff suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When decrypting, you get back the original byte sequence (result of your step 1), and then you can only guess whether these bytes denote characters according to the ISO-8859-1 or the UTF-8 encoding.

From a byte sequence, there's no way to clearly tell how it is to be interpreted.

A few ideas:

- You could migrate all the old encrypted strings (decrypt, decode to string using ISO-8859-1, encode to byte array using UTF-8, encrypt). Then the problem is solved once and forever.
- You could try to decode the byte array in both versions, see if one version is illegal, or if both versions are equal, and if it still is ambiguous, take the one with higher probability according to expected characters. I wouldn't recommend to go that way, as it needs a lot of work and still there's some probability of error.
- For the new entries, you could prepend the string / byte sequence by some marker that doesn't appear in ISO-8859-1 text. E.g. some people follow the convention to prepend a Byte Order Marker at the beginning of UTF-8 encoded files. Although the resulting bytes (`EF BB BF`) aren't strictly illegal in ISO-8859-1 (being read as `ï»¿`), they are highly unlikely. Then, when your decrypted bytes start with `EF BB BF`, decode to string using UTF-8, otherwise using ISO-8859-1. Still, there's a non-zero probability of error.

If ever possible, I'd go for migrating the existing entries. Otherwise, you'll have to carry on with "old-format compatibility stuff" in your code base forever, and still can't absolutely guarantee correct behaviour.

Comment: The first suggestion is a very good one! +1

Comment: Definetly agree that migration would be the best solution and I have to look into that more closely... only thing is that I have 300+ different keys and 3000+ values so it's somewhat terrifying to do the migration =/

@Andreas has a also provided a good solution that I believe is somewhat the same as you suggest in the second option.

Comment: @Jokkeri To me, keeping compatibility kludges forever is much more terrifying than writing an ad-hoc migrator and running it once. I've got some personal experience with kludges like that.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff  Agree on that for sure. It is also much simpler to do the migration now that only one type of encoding exists. Would be terrible if there would be values mixed with UTF8 and ISO-8859-1.
I think I will sacrifice the work now for the future and go with the migration you proposed

Answer (score 2):

When decoding bytes to text, don't rely on the `�` character to detect malformed input. Use a strict decoder. Here is a helper method for that:

```java
static String decodeStrict(byte[] bytes, Charset charset) throws CharacterCodingException {
    return charset.newDecoder()
            .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
            .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
            .decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes))
            .toString();
}
```

Here is the corresponding strict encoder helper method, in case you need it:

```java
static byte[] encodeStrict(String str, Charset charset) throws CharacterCodingException {
    ByteBuffer buf = charset.newEncoder()
            .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
            .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
            .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(str));
    byte[] bytes = buf.array();
    if (bytes.length == buf.limit())
        return bytes;
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, buf.limit());
}
```

Since ISO-8859-1 allows all bytes, you can't use it to detect malformed input. UTF-8 is however validating, so it is very likely to detect malformed input. It is however not 100% guaranteed, but it's the best we get do.

So, try decoding using strict UTF-8, and then fall back to ISO-8859-1 if it fails:

```
static String decode(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        return decodeStrict(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(decode("señor".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))); // prints: señor
System.out.println(decode("señor".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))); // prints: señor
System.out.println(decode("€100".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))); // prints: €100
```

Comment: +1 This is worth to try, I was actually using `Charset.forName(strCharset).encode(charBuffer);` which seems to use `CodingErrorAction.REPLACE` by default and I guess is resulting to '�'

Comment: @Jokkeri Correct, and we want `REPORT`, i.e. an exception, so we can do the fallback from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

I had to face a similar problem. The application I am working in should accept both `basic Latin` and `Latin extended-A` characters. The main problem was with accented characters (such as éèêàa...).

I tried using regex, encoders, decoders, etc. Finally, I ended up with this, which works fine for me.

- First, remove all accentuated chars using `StringUtils` from Apache
- Then check for each char alphabet, checking the Unicode block

```java
    public class EncodingUtils {

    private static final List<Character.UnicodeBlock> SUPPORTED_ALPHABETS = List.of(
        Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN,
        Character.UnicodeBlock.LATIN_EXTENDED_A);
     
            
            public boolean hasWrongEncodedChar(final String text) {
                return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(text) && 
                    StringUtils.stripAccents(text).chars().anyMatch(value ->
                       !SUPPORTED_ALPHABETS.contains(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(value)));
            }
}
```